# Is asking for ideas on what topics to write about of an anime on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

I was interested in writing a short research paper or analysis paper on the anime Shin Sekai Yori, however, I was not sure what type of thesis or main argument/idea to pursue/think about. I had a couple of ideas but wanted to discuss them with this site.

Is asking for such a request on or off topic?

Also, once I have decided my topic, is it on topic to discuss some of my analysis of the anime on this site? Or just ask for general suggestions on what people might feel/think on the topic?

Comment: This is the sort of thing that would probably be better suited for an anime forum somewhere. By its very nature, the question "What should I write about?" has no correct answer, which makes it not a great fit for this site. If you'd like, though, feel free to stop by [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/), where you might find people to bounce ideas off of.